# JQuery return only values that contain a specific string

Tags: jquery

Learning jQuery and need some help.

I have some simple image and text boxes. In the box (.box) is a text field (.category) that contains a letter, either D, L, or C.

I want to return only those boxes that contain the letter D.

This code outputs all the box values (D, D, D, L, L, C).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var boxValue = $('.box').find('.category').text();
    if($("boxValue:contains('D')")){
        console.log(boxValue);
    }
});
```

Why does it return all of them?
How do I get it to return only those with the letter 'D'?

Comment: Text fields have a value, not inner html.  `text()` will get the innerText of an element, but you want the value of it.  So use `val()` instead.

Comment: Paste the html too.

Comment: Also, `$("boxValue:contains('D')")`, ignoring the invalid syntax, will always return a jQuery object.  And objects in javascript are truthy.  So the conditional will always be true.

Comment: You don't use jQuery selectors to test the contents of a string. You can use `if (boxValue.includes("D"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your html:

```
<div class=box>
    <input class=category value="D" />
    <input class=category value="L" />
    <input class=category value="D" />
</div>
```

You can filter the elements with value equal to `D`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var box = $('.box').find('.category').toArray();    
    var filter = box.filter(x => x.value === 'D');
    console.log(filter);
});
```